# swift ios is there a way to add tab bar into an existing view controller instead of adding and using tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

in swift ios is there a way to add tab bar into an existing view controller instead of adding and using tab bar controller. Thank You.Is it done programmatically or there is a menu in xcode where we can add tab bar menu to an existing view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar) on UITabBar states you can add a UITabBar as a standalone control in your app.  You can add them programmatically or to a nib or storyboard scene, to an existing UIViewController.

Just add one like you would other controls.